# My Grandfather's Final Message

Tags: logical-deduction, cipher, enigmatic-puzzle, rebus

As my grandfather reached the end of his long and satisfying life, I sat by his bedside and asked him what advice he could give me to help me in my own. Unable to speak, he pointed to his bedside cabinet where I found **this** curious puzzle!

[image: My Grandfather's Final Message]

This made me smile. It was typical of my grandfather who loved language and riddles. It took me a while, but I finally solved the puzzle and decoded his message!

**CAN YOU:**

**1. Tell me his final message**

**AND**

**2. Explain the cipher!**

A clue (if you need it):

> I asked my grandfather if he could give me a clue to the cipher, and he just held up 4 fingers. It helped me - perhaps that will help you too?

A second clue (if you need it):

> I quickly figured out that my grandfather didn't mean the number 4. He was never much of a numbers man and much preferred riddles and wordplay.

A third clue (if you need it):

> I realised that my wordsmith grandfather must have meant the *word* "for", and that decoding the message involves exchanging one letter *for* another. But which letters? Surely the images next to each letter are involved...

Comment: Note that you can *almost* form the word "Minkoswky" with the letters given. Does he has a certain cipher?

Comment: Clue 3 tells you HOW the cipher works. You need to work it out. The correct answer needs to show working out.

Comment: Because the `SO!` seem to be sort of separate from the other letters, I thought this might be a key. One can notice that, to go from `S` to `O` one needs to go back **4** spots in the alphabet. Doing the same for the whole text yields something as (from top to bottom, first the left line and then the right line): `OK! EJIK UEZNQGKS`. Doing the same **4** spots further in the alphabet yields the equally non-elusive: `WS! MRQS CMHVYOSD`. Just reporting what seems like a dead end.

Comment: @VincentMiaEdieVerheyen I like to think I have given enough clues within the main question and the subsequent clues to indicate that the "cipher" is not mathematical. In fact I hope "cipher" is the right word! There are puzzles within the puzzle. The only additional thing I will give away is that the board should be viewed as two halves, left and right.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Complete Answer:

> KNOW YOUR IDIOMS! this anagrams from the letters

If this is correct, it seems that we must

> form idioms with the icons, then replace the icons with the corresponding letters.

Here are my guesses so far...
1st (numbering 1-16, down first for the images)

> An EYE *for* an EYE swaps K (1) and S(14)

2nd:

> HORSES *for* COURSES swaps N (6) and (2)

3rd:

> my KINGDOM (crown) *for* a HORSE swaps exclamation (3) and O (15)

4th:

> MONEY *for* NOTHING swaps W (16) and _ (4)

5th:

> MONEY *for* (OLD) ROPE swaps I (5) and Y (9)

6th:

> DOWN *for* THE COUNT swaps U (13) and M (7)

7th:

> JUST(ice) *for* KICKS swaps O (8) and R (12)

8th:

> PLAY *for* TIME swaps I (10) and D (11)

Hint:

> Each answer uses *for* which matches up with Grandpa's clue

Which gets me to:

> [image]

Comment: I imagined some people would resort to working backwards, which is why I insisted the correct answer must include an explanation. This way the final answer becomes another clue. Very meta. You're on your way!

Comment: Just to be clear - the correct answer will show not only the final message but also the idioms used to get the letters in that order.

Comment: Perhaps ROT13(gevcyr pebja ubefr enpr) is involved, especially given the timing.

Comment: @cobaltduck No, but you are starting to think about what the symbols represent. Remember you are looking to substitute one *for* another.

Comment: ROT13(gvzr vf zbarl)?

Previously deleted comment after thinking it was in the answer

Comment: Keep it up! you're doing great!!

Comment: @Klyzx Good guess, but not quite right. None of the idioms contain the word ROT13(vf) - have a look at arbitrahj's answers so far and you'll see a pattern.

Comment: A well-earned green tick @arbitrahj!